# Recognize numbers(1-100) in audio file in android

Tags: android, machine-learning, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I want my app to recognize numbers(1-100) spoken in an audio clip offline. I didn't find any tutorial. How can I do it?

I prefer not using any API.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, This site is for specific programming questions, Questions asking for tutorials is considered off-topic. Questions as broad as yours is also considered off-topic. Here is a Graduate (post college degree) course on speech recognition to give you an idea of what you need to know: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-345-automatic-speech-recognition-spring-2003/

Answer (score 1):

Well unless you are going to create the classes yourself to recognize speech, you should use the SpeechRecognizer API for Android.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html

There are some examples available on mykong and this one on Android hive:

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-speech-to-text-tutorial/